# UPDATE QUERY IN ACCESS 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

Ok, so I have a table that is populated from a generic crosswalk. But I have a second crosswalk that I need the values to replace those in the original table. Here is an example.

When i run the generic crosswalk the following results would return. (There are more columns, but they don't matter)

PAT/              FCP/        Service Line/      Business Manager

RT 646A40021/     123/         Logistics/           John Smith

However, our Logistics department has determined that that PAT belongs to Medicine, so I created another crosswalk that

PAT/                Service Line/      Business Manager

RT 646A40021/       Medicine/          Joan Jackson

Most of the PAT's that belong to FCP 123 will stay with Logistics, but That one in the second table needs to reflect Medicine rather that Logistics.

I need a query or Code that will look for the look for the PAT to match in both lists and then change the Service Line and Business Managers values in the first list.

The Tables names are Open Orders by Service Line Payables and FMS-Logistics Crosswalk respectively.

I can email the tables for a more specific example. I cannot write SQL code so for me that is not an option. I've tried several avenues to complete this task, but I have failed miserably. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT A.PAT, A.FCP, A.[Service Line], A.[Business Manager]
FROM Open Orders by Service Line Payables AS A LEFT JOIN FMS-Logistics Crosswalk AS B
ON A.PAT = B.PAT
WHERE B.PAT IS NULL

UNION

SELECT A.PAT, A.FCP, B.[Service Line], B.[Business Manager]
FROM Open Orders by Service Line Payables AS A INNER JOIN FMS-Logistics Crosswalk AS B
ON A.PAT = B.PAT
;
```

The first part of the UNION query will select everything in *Open Orders by Service Line Payables*  here no matching record is found in *FMS-Logistics Crosswalk*. The second part will add to this everything from *FMS-Logistics Crosswalk* where it matches on the PAT value.

You only need to add the other fields in the first table to the SELECT statement of both parts as follows:

```
A.PAT, A.FCP, A.[Service Line], A.[Business Manager], A.nextfield, A.[another field],...
```